# Error when using `refund::prf` without model intercept

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to run a functional data analysis model with scalar-on-function and on scalar regression in **R**. But by removing the intercept I'm getting the following error (the example is based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844746/extract-coefficient-functions-from-a-fitted-pfr-object-from-refund-r-package)),

```
library(refund)
data(DTI)
DTI1 <- DTI[DTI$visit==1 & complete.cases(DTI),]
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

fit_af <- pfr(pasat ~ -1 +sex + case + af(cca, k=c(5, 8), bs="ps"), data = DTI1)

#Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:9: unexpected symbol
#1: pasat~0 sex
#            ^
#Calls: pfr -> formula -> formula.character -> str2lang
```

How can I remove the intercept from a `pfr` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Running `prf()` in the debugging mode identifies the problem. When there is no intercept, it does:

```
if (!attr(tf, "intercept")) {
  newfrml <- paste(newfrml, "0", sep = "")
}
```

which I think should be fixed to

```
if (!attr(tf, "intercept")) {
  newfrml <- paste(newfrml, "0 +", sep = "")
}
```

Consider reporting this Stack Overflow thread, i.e., `https://stackoverflow.com/q/72856108` to package maintainer Julia Wrobel: julia.wrobel@cuanschutz.edu

---

**Note:** This was tested using the latest **refund_0.1-26** to date (released to CRAN on 2022-04-16).

Comment: thanks, see https://github.com/refunders/refund/commit/da27f2e3d459bd80f5f0edfefd777f20039021cc